# "so much like" in the non-predicative position

Tags: phrase-usage

I came across the expression "I like riding bicycle so much like you" by a non-native speaker (a child who meant "...as much as you"). And it grated on my ear. But I concede he might have learnt this cliche in his English study and could be misusing it.

Wouldn't "so much as you" fit better if any with "so" is pertinent here at all?

Comment: It is non-idiomatic and you provide no research to show that it does exist. Your son is so much like you.

Answer (score 0):

What the child said is actually possible, if it's punctuated differently:
"I like riding the bicycle so much, like you!"
In that use, "so much" means a great deal, and the phrase "like you" modifies the whole sentence. It could be said with changed word order:
"Like you, I like riding the bicycle so much!"

We can assume the child, a non-native English speaker, didn't intend that. So, let's consider the phrase you suggested, "**so much as you**".

It's possible, and it occurs in the title and first line of a poem:
[Poeticious Edward Thomas](https://www.poeticous.com/edward-thomas/no-one-so-much-as-you)
No one **so much as you**
Loves this my clay,
Or would lament as you
Its dying day.

I searched for the phrase "so much as", with and without "you".  I found that the phrase is used more often in a negative sense, as in the quote above, and in these examples:
"Not so much as a peep!" (telling a child to be quiet)
"Not so much A, as B" meaning, more B than A.

This may be a "negative polarity item", one that is not used in a positive sense:
[Wikipedia "polarity item"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item)

Since the example you started with is not negative, and since "so much as" sounds very old-fashioned, you should probably just use "as much as you".